# Reactjs tutorial

Tags: truffle, react

I am following the following tutorial:
[Reactjs example](https://www.trufflesuite.com/guides/getting-started-with-drizzle-and-react)

When I run "npm start" as written in the tutorial, a window pops up and I am getting following error message:

> ./src/index.js Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a
> default export (imported as 'App').

My index.jsis given below:

My index.js is given below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { Drizzle } from "@drizzle/store";
import MyStringStore from "./contracts/MyStringStore.json";
/*ReactDOM.render(
<React.StrictMode>
<App />
</React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
*/

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: https://bit.ly/CRA-vitals
//reportWebVitals();
// import drizzle functions and contract artifact

// let drizzle know what contracts we want and how to access our test blockchain
const options = {
contracts: [MyStringStore],
web3: {
fallback: {
type: "ws",
url: "ws://127.0.0.1:9545",
},
},
};
// setup drizzle
const drizzle = new Drizzle(options);
ReactDOM.render(<App drizzle={drizzle} />, document.getElementById('root'));
//NOTE index.js should be the same as given after the line: 
//Once that is complete, your index.js should look something like this:
//at: https://www.trufflesuite.com/guides/getting-started-with-drizzle-and-react
```

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi

Comment: It does not seem Ethereum related. You should try on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your App.js file include `export default App;` as the last line.